# Can you get prestige raid gear from Benedict 99-40?

Tags: destiny-2

In the prestige version of the Leviathan raid you receive the same Calus Tokens you have been from the normal raid, these you can turn in for random gear and guns at the vendor Benedict 99-40. But upon doing so I received the same armor from the normal raid and not the new prestige raid.

Is it possible to get prestige raid gear from the vendor or only from inside the prestige raid? And do you have to do something such as fully beat the prestige raid first to unlock the possibility?

Comment: I've heard no, but I don't have any proof either way. It makes sense that you can't get prestige mode gear since you get the same tokens from both modes (how would the vendor know what type of gear to give?).

Comment: @Adeese I didn't think so but the way I imagine it could work is once beaten the entire prestige raid it would add the gear into the loot table, but that's probably hoping too much from bungie.

Comment: I think in Datto's video on Prestige mode (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr5f4_9tjJ4) he said that you get the same tokens in Prestige mode on normal, and only the normal gear is in the loot table for the vendor engrams.

Comment: @Adeese That definitely seems to be the case, if you would like to add an answer with that proof I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Datto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr5f4_9tjJ4), the tokens you get from completing encounters in the Prestige mode of the raid are exactly the same as the tokens you get for completing encounters in the Normal mode. When you turn them in, they are completely identical, and the engrams only have the Normal mode items in their loot table.